# In a .net core WebAPI project, which events cause the http request to be cancelled?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, cancellationtokensource

Lets say I have a regular website, no front end frameworks, just plain old forms, buttons and nav links and I use pure javascript to call the webAPI to save forms, get data, etc.

My WebAPI uses cancellation tokens.

What would cause the the request to be cancelled and therefor send a cancelled token through to my webAPI project.

I know I can manually abort the request or if theres a timeout, but what other things can cause the cancellation to happen?

My main concern is if the user fills out a large form and for whatever reason the api request to save the form is taking long, would a navigate away from the page, closing the browser/tab call the cancellation and my db update wouldn't complete?

Comment: if the user refreshes the page while it is still busy, the `CancellationToken` will be set and if your db operation is still going, it will be requested to cancel and assuming Sql Server, unless it is in a transaction, it will not rollback. Not sure about closing tabs but most likely the token will also be set.

Comment: No, once the db is in progress it would cancel if the endpoint handles cancellationtokens and the front-end manually sends a cancellation token through.  Navigating away will not cause the front-end to send cancellationtokens to any open long running api requests.  I would have assumed a refresh would also not cancel the request, but line up another request, unless this is handled manually from js.

Comment: Another concern might be your command timeout if using sql server.  I think by default it's 30 seconds so if your query is taking longer than that to save then you may hit timeout issues there but that would be a long time to save a form.

Answer (score 0):

Not awaiting `asyn` method, calling `async void` method, trying to perform work on different thread while releasing the original tread. All of these issues are releasing the caller and then DI disposes all types created to serve  you request. For example you you have a class

```
public class SomeProcessor
{
    public async Task ProcessAsync(string payload)
    {
        // some code
        await Task.Delay(1000); // some async action
        // some more code
    }

    public async void ProcessAsyncVoid(string payload)
    {
        // some code
        await Task.Delay(1000); // some async action
        // some more code
    }
}
```

Then you inject it in your controller and use it like this:

`_processor.ProcessAsync(payload);`

or this:

`_processor.ProcessAsyncVoid(payload);`

and *NOT* `await` it. Your controller method will return and DI will dispose `SomeProcessor` class killing you logic. In logs you will see it as `OperationCanceledException`.